# Images wont load

Tags: html, css, image, load

I am currently doing an assignment for school and my teacher has sent all the project photos which I have saved. The only problem is they will not show up no matter what I try doing.

ex. the image is named "photo1.jpg" and I did:

```
  <img src="photo1.jpg">
```

But the image  will not load. if anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about `<img src="photo1.jpg" />`?

Comment: Please consider posting part of your code next time.

Comment: sorry the code did not show up. I did do <img src="photo1.jpg" />

Comment: Then much like everyone else is saying, your photo is probably not in the right place with your HTML document. Based on that code, your image should be in the same folder where your HTML document is located in.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean on a webpage then the use this code to generate the image:

```
<img src="photo1.jpg"/>
```

Keep in mind that the photo1.jpg needs to be in the same directory as the file (webpage) calling it.

Comment: Ok I moved all the photos to the same folder and its working. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  If you find your answer make sure to mark the answer as useful so everyone knows an answer was found.  You can also create an image folder as Rinner stated and then just use "images/photo1.jpg".  Just make sure images is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="photo1.jpg"></img>
```

Don't forget that this links current page folder. If you have in eg. in images directory, then use

```
<img src="images/photo1.jpg"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of the image. It should be in the same folder

```
<img src = "photo1.jpg" />
```

if it is not, and it has its own image folder inside your project you can do it like this

```
<img src = "imagesFolder/photo1.jpg" />
```